# Assertion error while reading excel file when filepath is accepted using tkinter

Tags: python, excel, pandas, tkinter

i am trying to create a GUI for my script, initially I hardcoded the filepath in the script but now I am trying to create a GUI using tkinter which will let the user browse to the file and run the script.

here is what works:

```
filepath = "E:\\testing in python\\book.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(filepath,sheet_name="mysheet")
```

this is what I am trying to do using tkinter:

```
filepath=""
def open_file():
    filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/", title="select file")
    # print(filepath) # it's printing the file path
 
browse_text = tk.StringVar()
browse_btn = tk.Button(root,command=lambda:open_file(),textvariable = browse_text, height=2, width = 10,font = ('Arial',10) )
browse_text.set("Browse")
browse_btn.grid(column = 2, row = 1)
df = pd.read_excel(filepath,sheet_name="mysheet")
```

i am getting this error:

```
File "D:\testing in python\script.py", line 64, in <module>
    df = pd.read_excel(filepath,sheet_name= "mysheet")
File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 336, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1071, in __init__
    ext = inspect_excel_format(
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 947, in inspect_excel_format
    assert content_or_path is not None
AssertionError
```

What would be the best way to tackle this issue?

Comment: When you print `filepath`, what do you get? If it is an empty string, that might mean that the user pressed `Cancel`.

Comment: i am getting the correct filepath, when printing

Comment: Move `df = pd.read_excel(filepath,sheet_name="mysheet")` just after the `filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(...)`

Comment: It ia because filepath is defined first as an empty string and its value will change only if the user presses the button. Put the read excel function inside the browse function

Comment: @Sujay Even if the button is pressed, `filepath` is a local variable.

Comment: i moved the read_excel line to just after filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(....), but still same error @TheLizzard

Comment: @Tarandeepsingh Did you make sure that it is part of the function (you need to also indent it)

Comment: thank you @TheLizzard, actually i thought filepath is a global variable so It should hold its value when assigned inside the browse function, but that wasn't the case